# How to read date from two different inputs?

Tags: date, spring-mvc, spring-form

I render my field on jsp into two inputs like this:

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern='dd/MM/yyyy' type='date' value='${campaign.beginDate}' var="startDate"/>
<form:input path="startDate" id="startDate" name="startDate" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text" value="${startDate}"/>

<fmt:formatDate pattern='HH:mm:ss' type='date' value='${campaign.beginDate}' var="startTime"/>
<form:input path="startTime" id="startTime" name="startTime" data-format="hh:mm:ss" type="text" value="${startTime}"/>
```

Now I want to read date into same single Date object into my controller.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Use **hidden** input field that contains date along with time and read in controller.

for example:

```
 <form:hidden id="<id>" path="<path>" />
```

OR update the value of hidden field before submitting the form.

---

Use *jQuery* to update the value in field before submitting the form:

```
$("#form-id").submit(function(event) {
    var startDate = $('#startDate).val();
    var startTime = $('#startTime).val();

    $('#startDateTime').val(<pass the date and time here>);
});
```

Comment: at this case will be cool if Icould exclude startDate and startTime from http request